# Devexpress mvc gridview in NavBar

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress, partial-views

I want to have navbar with 2 groups and gridview in each group.
My gridviews are in partial views

I use them like this:

```
Html.RenderPartial("ManagersGridPartial", Model)
```

Problem that i cant add  partial view in group.Items

```
@Html.DevExpress().NavBar(settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "managersNavBar";
        settings.AutoCollapse = false;
        settings.ExpandButtonPosition = ExpandButtonPosition.Right;
        settings.SkinID = "None";
        settings.Width = Unit.Percentage(98);
        settings.Styles.Item.Paddings.Padding = 0;


        settings.Groups.Add(group =>
        {
            group.Text = "First group";
            group.Items.Add("aaaaaaaasssssdddddd");
        });
        settings.Groups.Add(group =>
        {
            group.Text = "Second group";

            group.Items.Add("asdasdasd");
        });


    }).GetHtml()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is possible to specify a particular Item's content via the **MVCxNavBarItem.SetTemplateContent** method in the following manner:

```
settings.Groups.Add(group => {
    group.Text = "First Group";

    group.Items.Add(item => {
        item.SetTemplateContent(c => {
            Html.Partial("ManagersGridPartial", Model);
        });
    });
});
```